# Rest assured prematurely access response stream

Tags: asynchronous, inputstream, rest-assured

I need to verify a `text/event-stream` response for its content up to a certain point in time after the request was sent. The response stream is kept alive indefinitely for new events.

The following code does not work:

```java
given()
    .contentType(JSON)
    .when()
    .get("/mypath/") // This method blocks indefinitely, never reaching the "then" block
    .then()
    .response()
    .extract()
    .asString()
```

How can we close the response stream at a certain point to access what it has so far? Or perhaps intercept the underlying `InputStream` of the response asynchronously somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me:

```
    var inputStream = given()
    .contentType(JSON)
    .when()
    .get("/mypath/")
    .then()
    .extract()
    .response().asInputStream();

var lines = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
).lines();      

lines.forEach(str -> {

            if(str.isEmpty() || str == null){
                return;
            }

            System.out.println(str);

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**